# How do you get the item list on the right side in creative or survival?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've watched Minecraft videos and on most of them, people go to their inventory or press the "E" button, and there is a column on the right hand side showing all the items,crafting recipes, and ID names. You can switch it on and off. How do you get that column?

Answer (score 9):

That column as you put it, is from a mod called [NOT ENOUGH ITEMS](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/909223-164-smp-chickenbones-mods/). If you want that addition (and the others it offers) to the game, you need to install the mod.

Comment: As NEI is somewhat outdated (1.6.4 according to provided link), you may also want to look at Too Many Items (http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/140684-17213w48b-toomanyitems-in-game-invedit-dec-2/), which is up to date (1.7.2), and to my knowledge, updated more frequently. It isn't quite as full-featured as NEI, but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a mod, either Not Enough Items or Too Many Items.

If you want to get Not Enough Items (I don't know how to get Too Many Items) you need to get Minecraft Forge, Go to this website: files.minecraftforge.net/. Then open minecraft and close it again. Then you need to get Not Enough Items, [Get Not Enough Items For 1.6.4](http://www.skydaz.com/not-enough-items-mod-installer-for-minecraft-1-6-4/), [Get Not Enough Items For 1.7](http://www.playdota.com/forums/blog.php?b=148314). If your getting 1.7 version get 1.7.2 download. The for 1.6.4 open everything and install Not Enough Items. Then it should work. For 1.7 (I'm not to shore about this because I play 1.6). If you get a .jar file or something like that go into %appdata%.minecraft\mods and put the file in there. If you get some installer thing then install it and open minecraft and it should work!

Answer (score -2):

To get this list, you will need a popular mod called too many items. If you use a mac mods are difficult to install; seek help

Comment: You have to assume the poster is here looking for help.  Perhaps you could link to where you can download the mod.  And, you can also help find instructions on how to install it.